# Running Python script via ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to run a python script from an ansible script. I would think this would be an easy thing to do, but I can't figure it out. I've got a project structure like this:

```
playbook-folder
  roles
    stagecode
      files
        mypythonscript.py
      tasks
        main.yml
  release.yml
```

I'm trying to run mypythonscript.py within a task in main.yml (which is a role used in release.yml). Here's the task:

```yml
- name: run my script!
  command: ./roles/stagecode/files/mypythonscript.py
  args:
    chdir: /dir/to/be/run/in
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
```

I've also tried ../files/mypythonscript.py. I thought the path for ansible would be relative to the playbook, but I guess not?

I also tried debugging to figure out where I am in the middle of the script, but no luck there either.

```yml
- name: figure out where we are
  stat: path=.
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
  register: righthere
    
- name: print where we are
  debug: msg="{{righthere.stat.path}}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
```

That just prints out ".". So helpful ...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

try to use **[script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html)** directive, it works for me

my main.yml

```
---
- name: execute install script
  script: get-pip.py
```

and **get-pip.py** file should be in **files** in the same role

Comment: This is the better answer and I'm not even sure why I didn't suggest it other than more closely following the OP's original code. Use roles and then use the syntactic sugar around them such as the search paths for scripts/files and templates etc.

Comment: This solution run script on remote host.  @ydaetskcoR solution run on local (management) host.

Comment: if I am trying to run this I am getting error                                                                    name: Run a script using an executable in a system path
  script: /home/user/sample.py
  args:
    executable: python2.7

Comment: I create another python script to write a file which did work well , but dont understand why I am not seeing print statements

Answer (score 17):

If you want to be able to use a relative path to your script rather than an absolute path then you might be better using the [`role_path` magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) to find the path to the role and work from there.

With the structure you are using in the question the following should work:

```
- name: run my script!
  command: ./mypythonscript.py
  args:
    chdir: "{{ role_path }}"/files
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
```

Comment: That would screw up my directory I intend to run the python script in, but I suppose I can pass that as a param to the python script. Thanks!

Comment: Then simply change the `command` line to `command: ./"{{ role_path }}"/files/mypythonscript.py` if your Python script needs to be ran from some specific path (and obviously change the `chdir` arg to the path you want it to be)

Comment: I hope the entire value of chdir should be double quoted which could prevent syntax error.

Comment: I m not able to understand what role path is . I am trying to run python script which is on ansible server /home/user . but if I am providing path it does not work. I am getting errors

Comment: role_path points to the top level folder for the role, and the role specific folders - files, templates, task, etc - are below that.  e.g. if you role is name "myrole" role_path's value might be /home/user/project/playbooks/roles/myrole"

Answer (score 3):

An alternative/straight forward solution:
Let's say you have already built your virtual env under ./env1 and used pip3 install the needed python modules.
Now write playbook task like:

```
 - name: Run a script using an executable in a system path
  script: ./test.py
  args:
    executable: ./env1/bin/python
  register: python_result
  
  - name: Get stdout or stderr from the output
    debug:
      var: python_result.stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute the inline script without having a separate script file (for example, as `molecule` test) you can write something like this:

```
- name: Test database connection
  ansible.builtin.command: |
    python3 -c
    "
    import psycopg2;
    psycopg2.connect(
      host='127.0.0.1',
      dbname='db',
      user='user',
      password='password'
    );
    "
```

You can even insert Ansible variables in this string.

Answer (score 1):

To run a Python script via Ansible, you can use the command or script module in Ansible.

```
- name: Execute Python script
  hosts: target_hosts
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Run Python script
      command: python /path/to/script.py
```

Alternatively, you can use the script module if you want to execute a local script file on the target hosts. Here's an example:

```
- name: Execute Python script
  hosts: target_hosts
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Run Python script
      script: /path/to/local_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If the logic of your script could be represented as a one-liner, how about the below ?

```
- name: " Attempt to acquire hw vendor "
  shell: |
        sudo /usr/sbin/dmidecode | /usr/bin/grep Vendor > /var/tmp/machine_Vendor.txt
  become: true
```

Comment: The answer does not address the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run as part of gitlab runner. First run the below to get the python executable path.

- name: show python lib/site paths
  python_requirements_info:
- name: check for modern boto3 and botocore versions
  python_requirements_info:
  dependencies:

  - boto3>1.6
  - botocore<2

And then use that in the

- name: run the python script
  script: <python_path> <script_name>.py