# How to reset IAM user passowrd on multiple AWS acounts with one ansible command

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to reset one user password on multiple AWS accounts. Here we have 100 AWS accounts and when we get request for user reset password then we are login manual on the 100 AWS accounts and reset the user password.

I am looking how we can mange it by ansbible. Even how we can create user with command on all the 100 AWS accounts

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a script using the aws SDK.

I've normally used python's boto3 and it's pretty simple.

here you have the link of the documentation.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_access_key

Comment: Is not possible with ansible  ?

Comment: i am not sure, but you can run a python script with ansible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139711/running-python-script-via-ansible