# How to run a python script from a ansible playbook

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, yaml

Trying to create a yaml that will run a python script to connect ansible to other software frameworks.

The playbook looks like something along the lines of:

```
---
- host: all
  tasks:
  - name: Connect to some framework
    script: testscript.py
```

Is this correct syntax or is there more to add to the yaml file?

Comment: You might have a better chance to get an answer if you don't rely on people guessing the problem. What is actually going wrong when you run this playbook? Please don't replay in comments, edit your question.

Comment: Looks right based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139711/running-python-script-via-ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add the interpreter:

```
---
- host: all
  tasks:
  - name: Connect to some framework
    script: /path/to/testscript.py
    args:
      executable: /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You should pass the python binary to `args.executable`