# how to run python script with ansible-playbook?

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking, ansible, virtual-machine

I want to print result in `ansible-playbook` but not working.
python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

while True:
    print("I'm alive")
    time.sleep(5)
```

deploy_python_script.yml:

```
  connection: local
  become: true

  vars:
    python_script_src: /home/ubuntu/scripts/python_script.py
    python_script_dest: /opt/web_service/python_script.py
    python_script_mode: "0755"
    python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
    - name: Ensure destination directory exists
      file:
        path: /opt/web_service
        state: directory
        mode: "0755"

    - name: Copy Python script to server
      copy:
        src: "{{ python_script_src }}"
        dest: "{{ python_script_dest }}"
        mode: "{{ python_script_mode }}"

    - name: Run the script
      command: "{{ python_interpreter }} {{ python_script_dest }}"
      register: script_result
      become: true
      become_user: root

    - name: Check if script ran
      debug:
        msg: "Script ran: {{ script_output.changed }}"

    - name: Show output
      debug:
        var: script_result
```

I ran the following command:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost -vvv deploy_python_script.yml
```

result:

```
TASK \[Run the script\] \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*

task path: /home/ubuntu/ansible/deploy_python_scriptt.yml:27

\<127.0.0.1\> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu

\<127.0.0.1\> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo \~ubuntu && sleep 0'

\<127.0.0.1\> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "\` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp \`"&& mkdir "\` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100 \`" && echo ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100="\` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100 \`" ) && sleep 0'

Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/command.py

\<127.0.0.1\> PUT /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-17791bx4xmv_v/tmplblg_5p8 TO /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100/AnsiballZ_command.py

\<127.0.0.1\> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100/ /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'

\<127.0.0.1\> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-fqbwhdiehqpybtbtjwcnrafqdjqdbfbf ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709641109.322795-17936-40556479292100/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"' && sleep 0
```

Comment: Instead of `copy` and `command` it is recommended to use the [`script` module – Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html).

Comment: You might want to have a script that doesn't run forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Python script via ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139711/running-python-script-via-ansible) and many more which can be found by search ...

Comment: I also used ansible.builtin.script but it doesn't show the output... @U880D

Comment: As you can see from a lot of questions and answers here, in general the approach will work. Please take note that your script never ends, therefore no final result set is available which could be registered.

Comment: Does that mean that the text "I am alive" should not be printed every five seconds? @U880D

Comment: Right, that's the case, how the expected behavior is, and as it was designed in that way. See [Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) and [You can create variables from the output of an Ansible task with the task keyword `register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

Comment: OK
I think I used the same method:
tasks:
   - Name: Run a script
     script: /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/scripts/python_script.py
     register: script_result

   - name: Show output
     debugging:
       var: script_result.stdout

@U880D

Comment: As you can see, I put the output into the register first
And then I used script_result.stdout. @U880D

Comment: I do not get the last two comments. What is question regarding that ones?

Answer (score 0):

For a Python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

print("I'm alive")
time.sleep(5)
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - script: alive.py
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook script.yml -v
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [script] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  rc: 0
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: |-
    I'm alive
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
Wednesday 06 March 2024  08:00:00 +0100 (0:00:05.152)       0:00:05.241 *******

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    failed: false
    rc: 0
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      I'm alive
    stdout_lines:
    - I'm alive

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 5 seconds
```